# Group and Map a List with a gRPC List with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, grpc

I'm working with a gRPC service and I have a list of Hotels where It could happen that there is the same hotel repeated but with different rooms or quotes, I would like to group those Hotels with same id and add the different Rooms inside it. I'm trying to reach it with Linq but getting this error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField'

This is the block of code.

```
    private Grpc.CheckRateResponse BuildGrpcResponseResult(List<Hotels> hotelsList)
    {
        var listResult = hotelsList.GroupBy(h => h.Id)
                 .Select(g => new Grpc.Hotels
                 {
                    Id = g.Key,
                    Name = g.Where(c => c.Id == g.Key).FirstOrDefault().Name,
                    CategoryCode = g.Where(c => c.Id == g.Key).FirstOrDefault().CategoryCode
                    Rooms = g.SelectMany(h => h.Rooms).GroupBy(r => r.RoomId).Select(x => new Grpc.Room
                        {
                            RoomId = x.Key,
                            RoomName = x.Where(l => l.RoomId == x.Key).FirstOrDefault().RoomName,
                            Rates = x.SelectMany(r => r.Rates).Select(c => new Grpc.Rate
                            {
                                RateKey = c.RateKey,
                                RateType = c.RateType,
                                BoardCode = c.BoardCode
                            })
                        })
                 });

        Grpc.CheckRateResponse result = new Grpc.CheckRateResponse();

        result.Hotels.Add(listResult);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: the error is at RepeatedField.Add() and should accept IEnumerable<T>? did you try listResult.ToList()?

Comment: There are actually two problems, the first is that the compiler generates Rooms and Rates of class Grpc.Hotels as read-only fields, so no assignments can be made (Rooms = x;) only Rooms.Add (room) is aceptable. The other obstacle is that inside a Select you can't do a Rooms.Add (room).